# java: написать односвязный список

Tags: java

```
public class Node {
  public int value;
  public Node next;

  public Node(int value){
    this.value = value;
  }

  public Node() {

  }
}

public class List {
    Node head = new Node();

     public void add (int value) {

         Node element = new Node(value);
         Node walker = head;
         while (walker.next != null) {
             walker = walker.next;
         }
         walker.next = element;
     }

    public Integer getSize(){
         int size=0;
        Node walker=head;
        while(walker.next!=null){
        walker=walker.next;
        size++;
        System.out.println(size);
    }
    return size;

}
     public void print(){
         Node walker = head;
         while (walker.next != null){
             walker = walker.next;
             System.out.println(walker.value);
         }
     }
}
```

нужен односвязный список
всё работает, но есть одна пустая нода в начале списка, нужно её убрать

Comment: Это учебный вопрос. Добавьте пример кода или его закроют. Спасибо.

Comment: `Node head; // = new Node();`

Comment: Node head; // = new Node(); - а как в цикле тогда поменять?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Node head = null;

public void print(){
  Node walker = head;
  while (walker != null){
    System.out.println(walker.value);
    walker = walker.next;
  }
}

// аналогично - в add и getSize
```

Comment: Ну так если head = null, то это условие сразу не выполняется (walker != null)

Comment: @Yura А что Вы ожидали для списка, в котором ничего нет? `head` будет не `null`, когда Вы что-то добавите в список.

Comment: Можете написать как должен выглядеть метод add, я так понимаю у меня в нем проблема

Comment: @Yura Нет, я не буду писать за Вас, как должен выглядеть метод `add`.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.